# How can I convert a string containing html to html itself?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a following string variable:

```
string example = "<div class=\"content\">" + Environment.NewLine + "[some content here]" + "/div";
```

How can I render it as html markup in the page body?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Html-raw:

```
<body>
    @Html.Raw(example)
</body>
```

(However I would do it with caution. It is always best not to make HTML with strings if possible, as it poses a security risk and causes maintenance issues.)

Comment: Thanks) Faster than I could expect)